# After button having postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ispostback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button cmdTemp = null;
    try
    {
        cmdTemp = (Button)GetPostBackControl(this);
    }
    catch { }  
    FillTableDB();
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        if(cmdTemp == null || cmdTemp.ID == "btnNew" || cmdTemp.ID != "btnSave")
        {
            GenerateBlankTableHtml("");
        }
    }  
}

private void FillTableDB()
{
    //SQL QUERY
    //Select status from table 

    GenerateBlankTableHtml(status)
}

private void GenerateBlankTableHtml(string status)
{
   if(status=="")
   {
        btnNew.Style.Add("Display", "none");
   }
   else
   {
      //show status in label
     lblStatus.text=status;
   }

}

public static Control GetPostBackControl(Page page)
{
    Control control = null;

    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if(ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            if(c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return control;
}
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server"/>
<asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"
```

I have two functions  FillTableDB();GenerateBlankTableHtml(string status);
When status getting blank i have to hide btnNew otherwise showing status in label.
if label having status then and only then New study botton will displayed otherwise not.

**What i want when user click on button NEW then and only then i have to show label text with blank status Not click on save button What should i do.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this  
    if(IsPostBack)
     {                      
       if(btnNew.Style.Value == "Display:none;")
      {
             GenerateBlankTableHtml("");
      }                     
    }

   protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      GenerateBlankTableHtml("");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

do something like following.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" onClick="btnNew_click"/>
```

and now on that button new click.

```
 protected void btnNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnNew = (Button)sender;
        btnNew.Style.Add("Display", "none");
        lblStatus.text = string.empty;
    }
```

Comment: Jalpesh have to hide btnNew according to status.

Comment: this code will hide button - btnNew.Style.Add("Display", "none");